# Asymptotically monotonic sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, monotone-functions

Let $(u_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $$u_n \sim c n$$ where $c>0$.

Is it true that $(u_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is necessarily asymptotically increasing (i.e. that there exists an integer $k$ such that $(u_n)_{n \geq k}$ is increasing)?

I have a feeling that this is false, but I am unable to find a counter-example.

Comment: I think that “eventually” is the right term to describe a property which holds for all sufficiently large indices, not “asymptotically.” But English is not my first language, so I might be wrong.

Comment: That's a fair point! (I'm not a native speaker as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence
$$
 u_n = 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, \ldots = 
\begin{cases}
 n & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\
 n+2 & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
\end{cases}
$$
satisfies $u_n \sim n$, but is not eventually increasing.

For arbitrary $c > 0$ you get a counterexample with $(c u_n)_n$.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's false. Let $u_n= cn+ \epsilon\sin{n}$ never strictly increasing but satisfies the asymptotic criterion for small positive epsilon.

Comment: This is strictly increasing if $|\epsilon| < c$.  Proof:  $\frac{d}{dx} (cx + \epsilon \sin x) = c + \epsilon \cos x \geq c - |\epsilon| > 0$.  But it works if $\epsilon$ is sufficiently large compared to $c$.